# how to delete all the rows in the table which has name equals to myname

Tags: android, sqlite

I have the below code. Does this delete all the rows having name = myname?

```
return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, NAME + "=?", new String[] { myname });
```

If not, can you help me how to achieve it

Answer (score 0):

Which dbms do you use?
I would try

```
DELETE FROM databasename WHERE name = yourname
```

this is in mysql, but the sql from the different dbms is very similar

should work also on sqllite

Answer (score 0):

```
mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, NAME + "=" + myName, null);
```

Comment: Hey , I tried the above code, but it does not seem to be working.

Comment: My first statement is working fine. The table name was wrong there. Thanks.